# Pushing Git Repo to Remote Server

Tags: git, ssh

So I am trying to push a repo from my localhost to my VPS.

I have setup a --bare repo on my vps and a repo on my localhost.

I have used the following commands to push to the VPS:

```
# git remote add origin ssh://root@mysite.net/home/mysite/public_html/mygit/.git
# git push origin master
```

It pushes successfully, but what I need to be able to do is checkout the files from the VPS .git. But, when I try running 'git checkout' I get the error:

> fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree

I have tried editing the .git config file and editing/adding these lines:

```
[core]
bare = true
worktree = /home/mysite/public_html/mygit/

[receive]
denycurrentbranch = false
```

This allows me to run git commands, but the files wont checkout, and git tells me files have been deleted.

I am just a little bit confused. How should I be going about this?

Comment: are you running these commands on a clone - or on your bare repo?

Comment: I am running the commands on a bare repo on my VPS.

Answer (score 6):

Trying to perform checkouts on a bare repository is quite illogical - `checkout` is a command for updating your working copy/tree:

> git-checkout - Checkout a branch or paths to the working tree

A bare repository doesn't have a working tree.

### Setting up your git repos the normal way

So starting from zero, let's assume you are on your home/office computer:

#### Create bare repo

Create a bare repo for your project - or move your existing repo to some appropriate location:

```
ssh root@mysite.net
cd repos
mkdir repo.git ##give it a better name
cd repo.git
git init --bare
```

#### Make a clone for your site

```
ssh root@mysite.net
cd /home/mysite/public_html
git clone ~/repos/repo.git .
```

#### Create a local clone

```
cd mylocalsite/public_html
git clone root@mysite.net:repos/repo.git .
git push/pull etc.
```

### Update site automatically

Since your goal is to update automatically, You can use git-hooks to update the working copy that is your live site whenever you push to your repo.

Here's [a simple example](https://github.com/AD7six/git-hooks/blob/develop/recipes/update-local-working-copy):

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/mysite/public_html
git --git-dir /home/mysite/public_html/.git pull > /dev/null
```

save it as `/home/root/repos/.git/hooks/post-receive`, make it executable, and every time you push, it'll attempt to update your live site by issuing a pull

#### OR

you can forgoe the use of a bare repository and use your live site's checkout as your main/only repository. This is **not recommended** but if you choose to do so, you would do:

```
git remote add live root@mysite.net:/home/mysite/public_html/.git
git push live master
```

It'll give you an error about updating the currently checked-out branch, read the warning and understand what it means. If you decide you still want to do this you can allow it to work with:

```
ssh root@mysite.net
cd /home/mysite/public_html
git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore
```

Again **not recommended**, much better to have a bare repo and maintain your live site as a normal checkout.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I am going to give this a go now.

Comment: Okay so I've got the pushing working, from my local to my server. Now, how do I checkout the files from the repo on the server?

Comment: I get this message when trying to push:
stdin: is not a tty
/root/.bashrc: line 13: export: `PATH/root/local/bin:/usr/local/jdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin': not a valid identifier
Everything up-to-date

Comment: sounds like you're doing something quite weird - note that the error comes out of your `.bashrc` file and looks like it is nothing to do with your question. If you need hands on help I suggest using SO chat or #git on freenode.

Comment: @AD7six I have node.js app on VPS. Do I use these same commands to auto update my node app from github? So intead of public_html my .git file is in /root/mynodeproject/.git. What changes do I need to make to make my stuff work?

Comment: @codeinprogress please ask a question if you need to - don't leave comments on unrelated old questions.