# Git post-receive hook stopped copying files to web directory

Tags: linux, git, permissions, githooks

Disclaimer: I'm a git newbie.

I followed the following post: [Setting up your git repos the normal way (here on stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12527839/1022935) to get a --bare repo set up at `/home/www-data/themename.git` and a post-receive hook working that copied everything to my `/var/www/domain.com/htdocs/wp-content/themes/themename/` folder. (I followed the instructions on that post exactly). Everything was working perfectly.

However, today I wanted to take a look inside that `post-receive` hook and ran `cat  /home/www-data/themename.git/hooks/post-receive`. If you didn't notice, I accidentally placed two spaces after `cat` instead of one. Which overwrote everything in the file rather than displaying it. Looking back, I should have just used `nano`. So I opened the post again, and copied the code snipped from the post and pasted it into my `post-receive` hook again. But now it doesn't do anything. The files aren't copied.

Thinking that maybe it was a permissions issue, I ran `chown -R www-data:www-data` on `/var/www` and that didn't work. I also ran `chown -R www-data:www-data` on `/home/www-data` and that also didn't work. Lastly I ran `chmod +x /home/www-data/themename.git/hooks/post-receive` to make the file executable in case it stopped being, and that also doesn't work.

Also, `git pull` still works correctly in the `/var/www/domain.com/htdocs/wp-content/themes/themename/` directory.

Any suggestions to fix this? Or should I just create the repos and directories from scratch again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This started working again after the server was rebooted.